# Moving config files to spring cloud

Tags: java, spring

I want to move the configuration json files that are in Config folder in my project to spring cloud  To reduce the deployment time. These are masking config files used for masking the logging. Java 8 & spring 2.7 maven project.

Looking for sample code to solve the problem

Comment: Please check below article on Spring Cloud Config Server about externalizing configuration.  https://www.springcloud.io/post/2022-03/spring-cloud-config-server-step-by-step/#gsc.tab=0